# What do these computers' dots and lines mean?

Tags: what-the-golf

In the main hub, there are multiple flashing computers that display a series of dots and lines if you hit them twice. I've included 3 examples below, but there are quite a few of them (around 20?).

What are these computers saying?

[image: Computer 1]

[image: Computer 2]

[image: Computer 3]

Answer (score 3):

If you interpret the vertical lines as dashes, each sequence is valid Morse code, with each subsequence separated by spaces representing a single character, for a total of 4 characters each. Under that interpretation, the images say the following (guessing a little where some of the spaces are):

1. 2RET
2. 5SES
3. 8MHE

Comment: I wonder if the number is meant to show the order of the three characters in a longer sequence. \_\_\_ret\_\_\_\_\_\_ses\_\_\_\_\_\_mhe(\_\_\_)? With spaces somewhere

Comment: @Wrigglenite You seem to have been correct there.  [This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/WhatTheGolf/comments/foq2zc/the_what_the_golf_morse_code_easter_egg/) has several other decoded ones, but a different solution for 8.